# How to enable SSL/HTTPS in WCF Service?

Tags: wcf, ssl

I want to enable SSL/HTTPS in my WCF Service.
So I have found a site of Microsoft: **http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh556232.aspx**

But it doesn't function.
Is there something missing?

This is what I have:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service name="Service.Service">
    <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="Service.IService" bindingConfiguration="webHttpsBinding" behaviorConfiguration="restBehavior"></endpoint>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="restBehavior">
      <webHttp />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="webHttpsBinding" closeTimeout="00:00:20">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>    
</system.serviceModel>
```

I want to call the service from **jquery**. Use **ajax** and **getjson**.

Comment: What does `it doesn't function` mean exactly? Did you do the `<security mode="Transport">` bit in your config? Are you using an https URL to try and access the site? What happens?

Comment: I want to call the service from jquery (ajax, getjson).

Comment: And I get an 400 - Not Found Error when I want to test it like so: https://.../Service.svc/GetPeople

Comment: Does somebody has some ideas?

Comment: I get an EndpointNotFoundException.